# RenderScript includes native binaries for all the platforms

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, renderscript

Our Android project includes some native libraries and we support only `arbeabi-v7`. So the generate apk only includes native libraries for this architecture.

Lately we added `RenderScript` that causes the generated apk to include `librsjni.so` and `libRSSuport.so` native for all the supported platform i.e. `x86`, `arbeabi-v7` etc.

The `build.gradle` files changes to add `RenderScript` are:

```
defaultConfig {
    // Other configs

    renderscriptTargetApi 18
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

}
```

The generated apk libs folder looks like:

```
libs
 - armeabi-v7
     - librsjni.so
     - libRSSuport.so
     - Other native libs
 - x86
     - librsjni.so
     - libRSSuport.so
 - Other archs
     - librsjni.so
     - libRSSuport.so
```

This causes issues in phones where primary abi is non `armeabi-v7` as the run time may think that non `armeabi-v7` architecture are supported and tries to run it and app crashes.

As of now we have added the following to `build.gradle` :

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
}
```

and in `gradle.properties`:

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Though this solves the issue, but it does seems like a hack or non standard solution.

Is there a standard or recommended way to solve this issue?

Comment: IMHO **abiFilters** is a perfectly standard solution for your problem.

Comment: @AlexCohn Thanks for the reply. What I am concerned is the use of `android.useDeprecatedNdk`. Is there a way to exclude the libs with the "non depricated ndk"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only use prebuilt libraries, your best option is to employ the [splits](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html) feature:

```
android {
  …
  splits { 
    abi {
      enable true
      reset()
      include "armeabi-v7a"
      universalApk false
    }
  }
}
```